# Ember.js binding to computed property in Ember.Object from controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, binding, ember.js, properties, controller

For a while now I'm working with Ember js and so far I like it. Unfortunately I'm running into  a problem.

I'm trying to display and update a property in a controller based on a property in an Ember object.

A link to a jsbin is below

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cuqitufo/2/edit?html,output)

The object represents an item with two values and a count for each of those values.
When the count for a property is changed a new total (countA * valueA + countB * valueB) for the item is calculated. 
I do this for 4 items in the example.

Whenever the count on any of them changes I also want to change a total for the 4 items.
I do this by defining a property in the controller. The property seems to display on initial load but doesn't update when the count is updated.

I figured binding the value to the Ember Object would do the trick but I can't seem to get it working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently binding the `totalBoth` variable to the class definition and not an instance of a class, which just wont work. What you want to do is observe for changes in any of the instances.

Check out this updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/cuqitufo/6/edit

The trick is to use the [@each property for aggregate data](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/).

So you no longer need the binding, you just observe the calculatedTotal of each instance: `App.TypeNumbers.@each.calculatedTotal`:

```
totalBoth   : function(){
  var total = 0;
  App.TypeNumbers.forEach(function(item){
    console.log( item.get('calculatedTotal') );
    total += item.get('calculatedTotal');
  });
  return total;
}.property( 'App.TypeNumbers.@each.calculatedTotal' ),
```

Comment: You make it seem so easy :). Thanks a lot, this really helped me out.

Comment: Haha. Yeah.. I've been playing with Ember since November, and recently trying to answer questions on StackOverflow to reinforce what I've learned. Glad I could help!